# Userform Multipage disabling tab click

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have a userform with multipage tabs, within each tab there is a "next" command button that allows you to move onto the next tab if there are no errors (if there is an error, it prompts the user and sets the focus to the error on that tab).  When the userform is open, I can click the tabs to jump around without completing anything which defeats the purpose of my error handling.

Is there a way to disable tab selection? Or add a sub to the tab itself?

Thanks

Comment: You could use `MultiPage1_Change()` to trap that event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Style property of the Multipage to `fmTabStyleNone` (2).

Comment: That just made the tabs disappear?

Comment: Exactly. Why show the tabs when you have navigation buttons?

Comment: Excellent point, I didn't know it kept the multipages. Thank you!