# Change User Form Page in VBA Form

Tags: vba, excel, userform, multipage

Good morning!

I have an User Form in VBA Excel with multiple Pages.

I want to create a command button ("Next" button) that allow the user to change the page. What code should I use?

Comment: Are you using a Multipage Control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
If Me.MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Index<>Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count Then
    Me.MultiPage1.Value = Me.MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Index + 1
Else
    Me.MultiPage1.Value = 0
End If
```

Comment: In order to create a more accurate code i would like to exclude the possibility for the user to bypass the "Next" button and change page by clicking on it. I'm trying to enable and disable the various pages but I'm not solving the problem. Have you any suggestion?

Comment: Google : **excel vba userform multipage disable** : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766422/userform-multipage-disabling-tab-click    http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=53750 and http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/704934-visual-basic-applications-enable-disaple-pages-multipage-control.html