# Disable/Enable Tabstrip on Multitab based on Checkbox value- EXCEL

Tags: excel, checkbox, userform

I have a userform with a multitab containing 8 tabs. I require a user to use checkboxes on tab 6. I'm try to disable the user from selecting the next tab (tab 7) if Checkbox 1 and Checkbox 2 are left unchecked. They should only be able to access the next tab if they select one of the two checkboxes.

```
Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()
If Failed1.Value = False Or Passed1.Value = False Then
Me.MultiPage1.Pages(7).Enabled = False
Exit Sub
ElseIf Failed1.Value = True Or Passed1.Value = True Then
Me.MultiPage1.Pages(7).Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
```

I can't quite get the code to work the way I want it to. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

FYI - I'm a VBA n00b.

Comment: i thought you want "or" condition.. . you use "and" condition.

Comment: Asaf, thank you for your comment. I'm looking for both conditions to be present for the next tab to be disabled.

Comment: If Failed1.Value = False    OR Passed1.Value = False Then

Comment: I tried that but I'm not getting the results I'm looking for. Tab 7 is still active.

Comment: this is not exactly what you asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766422/userform-multipage-disabling-tab-click  and this one may help:http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=53750

Comment: I ended up using navigation buttons rather than having them navigate through the tabs, thanks for the link Asaf!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me.MultiPageName.Pages(index).enabled = false

Me = the form active where multipage is present
MulitipageName = named multipage
Index = place of the page to enable copied from:http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/534056-is-it-possible-to-disable-a-tab-page-on-a-multipage-userform.html